# Making a WHERE function that only runs if value is not empty/null

Tags: c#, sql, methods, visual-studio-2013, where-clause

So i'm currently making somewith with C# and SQL on visual studios 2013 and want to make a form where there will be several text boxes for entering in the search criteria for each field/column to help find records in a database faster.

The user will be able to enter in values into as many fields/boxes as they want. However, i'm unsure of how I would write the WHERE statement for it.
I know that if I do WHERE FirstName = '' it will show up nothing, meaning I must append the WHEREs on.

I assume it would not be a good idea to have something like

```
public void QueryName(string FN, string LN,etc,etc)
"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE "
IF(FirstName != "") THEN
+ "FirstName = 'FN'" + IF(LastName != "") THEN
+ "LastName = 'LN'"
```

as it would break (i assume) if it had a WHERE followed by nothing, and I can't start off each append part off as "WHERE" as the user decides what values it searches by.

So what i'm looking for is a way to make an SQL statement in C# using multiple values of the users choice, without it being longer and more complicated than it needs to be.

If i'm confusing anyone, I'll do my best to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (FirstName = '' OR FirstName = @FirstName) AND (LastName = '' OR LastName = @LastName
```

This approach can cause some performance issues.

I prefer build the sql query using C# to identify the filters that the user wants to apply, like that:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 1 = 1 /* Just to not care about if the where clause is needed */";

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName))
{
    sql += " AND FirstName = @FirstName ";
}

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName))
{
    sql += " AND LastName= @LastName";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
select * from YourTable a
where (isnull(@FirstName, '') = '' or a.FirtName = @FirstName) and 
      (isnull(@LastName, '') = '' or a.LastName = @LastName);
```

This code `isnull(@FirstName, '') <> ''` will check if the value provided is null, then make it empty, otherwise leave it alone. Then checks if it is empty. So if this condition passes, then it will never try to compare against the `FirstName` column.